# How change the horizontal space while the align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

This is my code, if one tests it the last term is all the way to the right, how can I change the horizontal spacing so that everything is to the left?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\scriptstyle#1}
\makeatother
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\int _0^1\arctan ^3\left(x\right)\:dx=\frac{1}{2}\beta \left(3\right)-2\int _0^1\frac{x\arctan ^2\left(x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx\\[5mm]
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+2\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{\arctan \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx}_{x=\tan \left(t\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-4\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}t\ln \left(\cos \left(t\right)\right)\:dt \\[2mm]
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+4\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}t-4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k}\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}t\cos \left(2kx\right)\:dt
\end{align*}
%\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok i think its more complete now

Comment: I completed your snippet and tested it. If you mean the last line ends  far to the right, this is due to the length of the formula in this last line. If you don't like it, you can split it after the `=`  sign. If 've misunderstood  the problem, pleave explain with more details

Comment: I actually want to move the whole aligned part to the left, is it possible?

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your output. Please also make your code compilable. Currently, you will receive an error message since you used `\end{large}` without ever haveing a corresponding `\begin...` command. Apart from that, please be aware, that there is no environment named `large`. Instead there is a switch `\large` that stays active inside a group or until another switsch is used. Do you get any warnings fom your code, probably along the lines of "Overfull hbox detected"? If so, please also mention this in your question.

Comment: @leandriis: What is ‘der Switsch’? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard: A switch with an extra "s". Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Don't be sorry – I found that rather funny. Remembered me some Lubitsch movie (not sure which one).

Comment: Unrelated, but your last line has two `\int` and only one `dt`.  That's probably a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide an additional line break in what's currently the final row (and omit the stray `\end{Large}` directive), your equation looks fine in my opinion.

Incidentally, none of the manifold `\left` and `\right` sizing statements actually do anything -- except mess up the horizontal spacing and create an awful lot of code clutter. Do omit them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \!\arctan^3(x)\,dx
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)
  -2\int_0^1 \frac{x\arctan^2(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\[3mm]
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2)
  +2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{%
  1+x^2}\,dx}_{x=\tan(t)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2)
  -4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t\ln(\cos(t))\,dt\\[2mm]
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2)
  +4\ln(2)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t \\ % <-- new linebreak
&\quad -4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t\cos(2kx)\,dt
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `multlined` environment defined in the  `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \arctan^3(x)\,dx
    &=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)
      -2\int_0^1 \frac{x\arctan^2(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\[3mm]
    &=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2)
      +2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{%
      1+x^2}\,dx}_{x=\tan(t)}\\
    &=\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2)
      -4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t\ln(\cos(t))\,dt\\[2mm]
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
\frac{1}{2}\beta(3)-\frac{3}{8}\ln(2)\zeta(2) +4\ln(2)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t \\ % <-- new linebreak
-4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t\cos(2kx)\,dt
        \end{multlined}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Still another variant, with some improvements: I've removed the plethora of useless `\left ... \right`, using a single `\bigl(...\bigr)` for  reaons of legibility. Other than that, I systematically used the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` for fractionary coefficients, which should not have, in my opinion, the same visual importance as fractionary expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int _0^1\arctan ^3(x)\:dx&=\mfrac{1}{2}\beta (3)-2\int _0^1\frac{x\arctan ^2(x)}{1+x^2}\:dx\\[5mm]
&=\mfrac{1}{2}\beta (3)-\mfrac{3}{8}\ln (2)\zeta (2)+2\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{\arctan (x)\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\:dx}_{x=\tan (t)}\\
&=\mfrac{1}{2}\beta (3)-\mfrac{3}{8}\ln (2)\zeta (2)-4\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}t\ln\bigl(\cos(t)\bigr)\:dt \\[2mm]
&=\mfrac{1}{2}\beta (3)\begin{aligned}[t] & -\mfrac{3}{8}\ln (2)\zeta (2)+4\ln (2)\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}t {}\\[-1ex] & -4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}t\cos (2kx)\:dt
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]